# how to run tensorboard on CoLab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

How to run tensorboard on CoLab?
!tensorboard --logdir logs/
this took a very long time with no display,
What showed was 
TensorBoard 1.15.0 at http://bcb8d733d00a:6006/

Answer (score 0):

Use `%tendsorboard`, see an example here.

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/tensorboard_in_notebooks.ipynb